# printing svg document from browser

Tags: javascript, printing, svg

I have been trying to print some svg file from my application from browser. But after printing the output the content is displaying at the left top portion of the paper occupying quarter of the page. Can anyone suggest me a way to make the content fit in the paper. Its very urgent. Solution at the earliest point will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried saving the SVG file and printing it with another application?

Comment: No, I haven't tried that yet. I am trying to convert it in pdf and then I will let the client to download the pdf. Later they can take print. But I want to take print from the browser itself before converting and that output should fit the paper.

Comment: If you're converting it to PDF anyway, why do you want to print the original from the browser?

Comment: Because Its client request. Downloading and printing is a two step process, so they want to print directly from the browser.

Comment: Do you have control over the SVG? Can you resize it?

Answer (score 0):

Printing from a browser tends to be pretty bad for regular Web pages too, but you could take a similar approach to some websites: Include some "View for Printing" button that opens a new page which shows your document in a print-friendly layout. You could have this button open your SVG directly (not embedded within a page) with a canvas sized to A4 or Letter dimensions/aspect ratio (or slightly smaller to account for typical margin settings).

Comment: THanks for the suggestion Mr Clafou. I have already tried this. Even from new window if I print, the output comes very small in the paper occupyinf left top of the paper.